# Element API relatedTo not working

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi

I'm creating a lazy load/infinite scroll based on the tutorial but I want it to grab entries that are in categories. It doesn't seem to be doing anything with it at all though. It's returning the list of all of the entries.

I have tried it passing in the category object, the category id, slug, title etc. All same result

```
<?php

use Craft;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;
use craft\web\View;

class TwigTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{

    public function __construct($settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function transform( $entry )
    {
        $oldMode = Craft::$app->view->getTemplateMode();
        Craft::$app->view->setTemplateMode(View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE);
        $html = Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate( $this->settings['templatePath'], [$this->settings['variableName'] => $entry]);
        Craft::$app->view->setTemplateMode($oldMode);

        return [
            'id' => $entry->id,
            'html' => $html
        ];
    }
}

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'lazy-load' => function() {

            // validate and decode settings
            $hashed_settings = Craft::$app->request->getParam('settings');
            $settings = [];

            foreach ($hashed_settings as $key => $value) {
                $value = Craft::$app->security->validateData($value);
                if($value === false){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    $settings[$key] = $value;
                }
            }

            // criteria
            $criteria = [
                'section' => $settings['section'], 
                'limit' =>  $settings['limit'],
                'relatedTo' => $settings['category'],
                'offset' =>  $settings['limit'] * Craft::$app->request->getParam('offset'),
                'order' => $settings['orderBy'],
            ];
        
            return [
                'elementType' => Entry::class,
                'criteria' => $criteria,
                'paginate' => false,
                'transformer' => new TwigTransformer($settings),
            ];
        },
    ]
];
```

Comment: Does it work if you hard-code a category ID in place of `$settings['category']`?

Comment: @BenCroker it does not

Comment: In that case something may be wrong with your setup. Does the entry query work in a regular Twig template?